# Creating a right-continuous function from an arbitrary function

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f: \mathbb{R}_+ \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is some function for which I know that $\lim_{q\uparrow t} f(q)$ and $\lim_{q\downarrow t} f(q)$ both exist and are finite for every $t$ along rationals. Next I define a new function $g(t) = \lim_{q\downarrow t} f(q)$. My question is as follows. Is $g(t)$ right-continuous? If not, what more do I need to impose on $f$ to make $g$ right continuous?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651427/is-the-right-limit-function-always-right-continuous/1651464#1651464

Comment: @QiyuWen Awesome. thanks