# Let $F: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be increasing and let $G(x)=F(x+)$. Then G is right continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, continuity

Let $F: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be increasing and let $G(x)=F(x+)$. 
Then G is right continuous.

I'm trying to prove this obvious statement using $\epsilon-\delta$ argument, but I can't find a satisfactory way to show this since $G$ itself is defined by limit. How can I show this? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651427/is-the-right-limit-function-always-right-continuous/1651464#1651464