# Discontinuity of second kind and right-continuity

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, analysis, continuity

While reading the book: Random Walk, Brownian Motion, and Martingales (https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-78939-8), I came across exercise 6 (picture below), where he is supposing that $f$ has no discontinuity points of second kind. From what I know these points should be in the domain of the function.

I was wondering how to prove a) if every rational was not a discontinuity point of second kind (check:https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities for a definition)

[image]

Comment: What is the source of this problem, and how does that source define "discontinuity of second kind"?

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651427/is-the-right-limit-function-always-right-continuous) answer your question?